# Как проверить строку на запрещённые символы в js?

Tags: javascript, строки, валидация

Как проверить строку на запрещённые символы в javascript? То есть например, я хочу, чтобы пользователь вводил только английские буквы, русские буквы, цифры, возможно символы наподобие `_` и всё. На остальное должна выводиться ошибка. Как реализовать это в js? К сожалению, не дружу с регулярными выражениями. (Может быть посоветуете что-то по регулярным в js, чтобы нетрудно было воспринимать)

Моя попытка:

```js
function isValid(username) {
    if (/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(username))
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

P.S. Может быть кто-то подскажет, какие символы обычно используют в логинах, а какие не используют? Или это всегда на усмотрение разработчика?

Comment: Какие символы хотите разрешить - такие и разрешаете. Это же ваш проект.

Comment: Добавлю лишь, что как бы Вы не проверяли на стороне браузера ввод пользователя, на стороне сервера всё равно придётся выполнять аналогичную проверку.

Comment: @XelaNimed, я слышал об этом, но не совсем понял, зачем это делать?

Comment: Проверка на сервере необходима, потому что злоумышленник может подделать любой запрос и послать его к вам на сервер. Все получаемые запросы на сервере вы должны обрабатывать так, как будто вы не знаете отправителя!

Comment: @Alex, на клиенте делают для удобства пользователя. А на сервере для безопасности. Представьте что вместо имени я написал `<script>while(1)alert()</script>`, сервер так и сохранил такое "имя" в базу даных и теперь на моей страничке, вместо имени будет выводиться этот тэг. Т.е. все, кто зайдут на мою страницу получат этот бесконечный вывод (страница зафризит просто). Почитайте о xss атаках. Либо что еще хуже, через имя злоумышленник сможет неявно работать с БД сайта. Почитайте так же о sql (no-sql) инъекциях.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`^` - значит начало строки, `$` - конец строки, `[A-Za-z0-9]+` - разраешить больше одного (либо один) символа буквы либо цифры.

```js
function isValid(username) {
   return /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(username)
}

console.log(isValid('Adam'));
console.log(isValid('Adam$%%@#@D)*FU(Q'));
```